# Get numeric part from the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query regarding to get number from any string in first occurence. For example

```
"10 Main Street"        would return 10
"34 10 Main Street"     would return 3410
"  34 10 Main Street"   would return 3410
"  34 - 10 Main Street" would return 34
```

Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumeric]
(@strAlphaNumeric nVARCHAR(Max))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
--WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

But this is not provide accurate answer,

```
select dbo.[GetNumeric]('  34 - 10 Main Street' )
```

Resultant is - 3410 //which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Here is logic that seems to do what you want:

```
declare @pattern varchar(8000) = 'asd   34-2 xx - 35 abc'
declare @firstnum int;

select @pattern = replace(@pattern, ' ', '');
select @firstnum = patindex('%[0-9]%', @pattern);

select substring(@pattern, @firstnum,
                 patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(@pattern, @firstnum, len(@pattern))) - 1
                );
```

EDIT:

To fix the problem with numbers at the end of the string:

select @pattern = replace(@pattern, ' ', '');
select @firstnum = patindex('%[0-9]%', @pattern);
select @firstafternum = patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(@pattern, @firstnum, len(@pattern))) - 1;

```
select substring(@pattern, @firstnum,
                 (case when @firstafternum > 0 then @firstafternum
                       else len(@pattern)
                  end) 
                );
```

Comment: Gordon, your code fails when the number is at the end of the string, for example "Main Street 3".